# array python, input string change to List and output int

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.4

someone can help me to solve that my problem?
that problem is,

if iam input int (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0) always error?

```
data = input()

array = list(data)

table = {" ":270,
         "a":0,
         "b":90,
         "c":180,
         "d":270,
         "e":0,
         "f":90,
         "g":180,
         "h":270,
         "i":0,
         "j":90,
         "k":180,
         "l":270,
         "m":0,
         "n":90,
         "o":180,
         "p":270,
         "q":0,
         "r":90,
         "s":180,
         "t":270,
         "u":0,
         "v":90,
         "w":180,
         "x":270,
         "y":0,
         "z":90,
         "0":180,
         "1":270,
         "2":0,
         "3":90,
         "4":180,
         "5":270,
         "6":0,
         "7":90,
         "8":180,
         "9":270,
         "!":0,
         "@":90,
         "#":180,
         "$":270,
         "%":0,
         "^":90,
         "&":180,
         "*":270,
         "(":0,
         ")":90,
         "-":180,
         "_":270,}



for i in range(len(array)):

    print(array[i])

    print(("{["+array[i]+"]}").format(table))
```

Error at :

ex : if am input a#2

```
print(("{["+array[i]+"]}").format(table))

KeyError: 2
```

Comment: int `2` vs string `'2'`? Try printing `data` and `array` first to help you debug... Since we don't know what's in there we can't really help. See [mcve]

Comment: You should post the complete Traceback.

Comment: a#2(input),

Output

a
0
#
180
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\*****\*****\table.py", line 59, in <module>
    print(("{["+array[i]+"]}").format(table))
KeyError: 2

[link](https://postimg.org/image/95bvujvbt/)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to construct an `[element_index]` the format specification language doesn't support. You can't quote `element_index` and the format language checks to see if `[element_index]` is an integer and passes that before it uses it as a string, unfortunately you need it to be a string and that doesn't work. If `array[i]` was say `'*'` it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't use integers as string keys to a dictionary for `element_index` in the format language. This is a limitation of the format language, it treats an integer `element_index` as an integer. Unfortunately this is not explicitly stated in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec other than saying:

> element_index     ::=  integer | index_string

```
>>> "{[2]}".format({'2':0})
KeyError: 2
>>> "{[*]}".format({'*':0})
'0'
>>> "{[2]}".format({2:0})
'0'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for the [*field_name*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> The field_name itself begins with an arg_name that is either a number
>   or a keyword. **If it’s a number, it refers to a positional argument**, ...

and

> Because arg_name is not quote-delimited, it is not possible to specify
>   arbitrary dictionary keys (e.g., the strings **'10'** or ':-]') within a
>   format string.

The grammar spec for *field_name* is shown as

```
field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
```

I think the parenthesis/brackets are saying that arg_name can be either a `dotAttribute` or an index expression, `[2]` so the arbitrary dictionary key of the form `'10'` limitation applies - if that is correct then the docs could be clearer.

```
>>> d
{'1': 123, 'a': 4}
```

Using `'''{['1']}'''` as the format string, returns a *double quoted* string which just doesn't work.

```
>>> '''{['1']}'''.format(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#98>", line 1, in <module>
    '''{['1']}'''.format(d)
KeyError: "'1'"

>>> d.__getitem__("'1'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#100>", line 1, in <module>
    d.__getitem__("'1'")
KeyError: "'1'"
```

Then using '''{[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)}''' for the format string creates an integer which is passed to `__getitem__`

```
>>> '''{[1]}'''.format(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#101>", line 1, in <module>
    '''{[1]}'''.format(d)
KeyError: 1
>>>
```

`.format` just cannot make a string that looks like `'2'` to be passed to `__getitem__`

---

If the dictionary has a *double quoted* key, then it works

```
>>> d["'1'"] = 'foo'
>>> d
{'1': 123, "'1'": 'foo', 'a': 4}
>>> "{['1']}".format(d)
'foo'
>>>
```

Comment: This refers to an different part of the specification namely `{<field_name>[<element_index>]}` the OP has issues with `element_index` not `field_name`. The documentation doesn't explicitly point out the limitation of `element_index` but does show: `element_index     ::=  integer | index_string`.

Comment: Just to show the difference `field_name` can't have `':'` in it but `element_name` can have any char except `']'`, e.g. `"{[:]}".format({':':0}) -> '0'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the same result with

```
data = input()

for char in data:
    print(char)
    print(table[char])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question has already been answered I wanted to point out another way you could convert characters to numbers without an extremely long dict.

```
chars = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_"

for char in chars:
    print(char, (chars.index(char)+3)%4 * 90)
```

To be honest I think the original way might be better because it's extremely obvious what it does, but I just wanted to show that there is an easier way.